# Third, Fourth, Fifth

Tags: word-sequence

A friend of mine made a simple bar bet, in which he wrote down a list of ten words. Turning it around to show me, he covered up the first two words with his hand. The eight words below his hand were the following:

THIRD
FOURTH
FIFTH
SIXTH
SEVENTH
EIGHTH
NINTH
TENTH

He bet me \$20 that I would not be able to guess the first words on the logically-ordered list on my first try, though I could name them in any order. Of course, I'm thinking, *I'll just say 'FIRST' and 'SECOND', easy $20.* So I did. And he removed  his hand. And much to my surprise, I was out twenty bucks for my haste.

What were actually the first two words on the list?

Comment: A slight variation (not worth another question): ___ Second Third Fourth Fifth Sixth Seventh ___ Ninth Tenth

Comment: never take a bar bet if you dont already know the answer

Comment: @supercat So what is the answer to your sub-question?

Comment: @Trenin: Unison and octave (musical intervals).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> WHOLE
>  HALF

were the first two words.

Comment: Correct. At first glance, one sees a sequence of ordinal numbers, but if the first two are WHOLE and HALF, they're a sequence of ever-decreasing fractions.

Comment: Although note that this only really works in American English - A British English speaker would likely never use "A fourth" instead of "A quarter".

Comment: @JonStory Don't think this works in American (or Canadian) English either; we say "quarter" too.

Answer (score 15):

Senior and Junior. The list was suffixes for descendants with identical names, such as King George IV, which is King George the Fourth.

EDIT: Answer 2
Whole and half. One whole, one half, one third, etc.

Comment: It's a good answer, but it's not the one I'm looking for. Normally, in that context, you wouldn't use "Third", "Fourth", etc... you'd use Roman numerals.

Comment: I'd also argue that this isn't true. The current British Monarch, for example, is Queen Elizabeth the Second. I've never heard of a monarch referred to as Senior or Junior.

Comment: @Jon This isn't specifically referring to monarchs. Many times, in the US at least, if a father and a son have the same first and last name, they are referred to as Junior and Senior.

Comment: Ah my apologies, the use of King George as a reference confused me :)

Comment: Yeah, it's just not common to see a name passed down to a 3rd generation, and fairly rare to see it passed down to a 4th generation.  The most accessible example people will be familiar with is historical royalty.

Comment: @generalcrispy:   Why the heck does it matter how you would write it down?

Comment: If I made this bet and gave this answer I'd be pretty mad if I didn't get the $20. And I'd immediately find this and get even madder: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_%28name%29

Answer (score 14):

They could be “Main” and “Second”.  In the town I live in (and perhaps in some other small towns) west-side streets parallel to Main are $2^{nd}, 3^{rd}, 4^{th}, 5^{th}$ etc.  (East-side streets are B, C, D...; *ie*, Main does double duty standing in for $1^{st}$ St. and A St.)

[image: map snip]

Comment: Thought this one too.